# Trying to use getIntent to pull user input from one tab to display into a new tab (fragment to fragment), getting a NullPointerException

Tags: java, android

This is my first time creating an app and I've run into a LOT of errors and mistakes. Please believe me when I say I've googled and tried many things to work through this error but I need a fresh set of eyes on this. I will post my bits of code, sorry if it looks like a mess but I've been trying so many things.

**Tab3MyLitters.Java**

```
public class Tab3MyLitters extends Fragment {

Button newLitter;
EditText newLitterName;
String tab3LitterName;



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab3_mylitters, container, false);

    newLitter = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.createNewLitter);

    newLitter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

    {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            newLitterName = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.newLitterName);
            tab3LitterName = newLitterName.getText().toString();
 Intent i = new Intent(Tab3MyLitters.this.getActivity(), NewLitter.class);

            i.putExtra("litter name", tab3LitterName);


            // Create new fragment and transaction
            Fragment newFragment = new NewLitter();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.container, newFragment);
            transaction.commit();

        }
    });

    return rootView;
}
```

**NewLitter.Java**

```
public class NewLitter extends Fragment {

TextView litterName1;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_litter1, container, false);
    return rootView;

}


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    Intent Extra = getActivity().getIntent();
    String litterName = Extra.getStringExtra("litter name");

    TextView litterName1 = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.text_view2);

    litterName1.setText(litterName);

}
```

**Logcat**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                                                                               at com.example.swift.breedrhelprv2.NewLitter.onCreate(NewLitter.java:43)
```

So the issue is: litterName1.setText(litterName);
litterName comes back as null. So you would think this meant that it wasn't getting passed from Tab3MyLitters, however at one point I had it passing through fine but I had to change a couple things (for other errors) and broke it again. I've tried to pass other strings through litterName1.setText and I also get the NullPointerException too. I had read that the issue might be because I'm trying to setText in onCreate/onCreateView but I was still having issues rearranging everything.

If anyone please could give me some guidance I would be very thankful.

EDIT:

**tab_litter1.xml**

```
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.swift.breedrhelprv2.MainActivity">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="70dp"
    android:text="IDK WHAT IS HAPPENING"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: `litterName1` is `null`. This means that there is no view with id `text_view2` in the current layout. Please show `tab_litter1.xml`.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I've edited my post with tab_litter1.xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One tip of initializing views in a fragment is always do that in `OnViewCreated()` method.

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    TextView litterName1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_view2);
    litterName1.setText(litterName);

}
```

**EDIT**

Okay, so another tip for passing data between fragments is using `Bundle`.

1. Put your data into a `Bundle` object

   ```
   Fragment newFragment = new NewLitter();
   Bundle args = new Bundle();
   args.putString("litter_name", your_data);
   newFragment.setArguments(args);
   // begin transaction
   getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
           .replace(R.id.container, newFragment)
           .commit();
   ```
2. Retrieve your data in the receiving `NewLitter` class

   ```
   private String litterName;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       if (getArguments() != null) {
           litterName = getArguments().getString("litter_name");
       }
   }
   ```

Of course, your `litterName` variable has to be declared as a field of your `Fragment` class.

Comment: You are wonderful. That solved my NullPointerException! But the textview does not show up.. Any ideas there?

Comment: @MikeM. Thanks. I found the method finally and deleted my comment.

Comment: @Da_Pz Thank you for updating your code. But I'm a bit ignorant, what do you mean the variable has to be declared as a field? I'm also getting an error with 'setArgument', it is a static inside a non-static method but if I try to make my method static everything else breaks. The complete error is: "non-static method X cannot be references from static content"

Comment: @omgtain I've edited my solution according to your code now, can you try again? By declaring as a field is like how you declare the `TextView litterName1`.

Comment: @Da_Pz Thank you for helping me through this. The new edit did help the static issue but the view still doesn't appear on the new fragment/xml. Could it be my xml not loading correctly? There is nothing in logcat that looks strange or helpful. Except for maybe this ? "Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView"
I don't have ListView in my XML though. I fixed constraints on my textview to ensure it wasn't that.

Comment: @omgtain Can you verify that `litterName` has the correct string in `OnViewCreated()` method? If yes, then this question is considered as solved. You might need to ask a new question to solve your new issue.

Comment: @Da_Pz Yes it does. Thank you. I've marked it as solved. I'll fiddle with it some more and then maybe ask another question later. :)

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you that `litterName1` is `null`. This means that there is no view with id `text_view2` in the current layout. Please show `tab_litter1.xml`.

Let's take a look at the fragment lifecycle. As you see in the graphic below, `onCreate()` is called before `onCreateView()`. This means that your XML layout file has not been inflated and the view with id `text_view2` does not yet exist in the activity.

In order to fix the problem, move all of the code from `onCreate()` to `onCreateView()` after you inflate the layout.

Note that you can change

```
TextView litterName1 = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.text_view2);
```

to

```
TextView litterName1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view2);
```

[image]

[Source](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)